# How to test SpringBoot JmsListener with JUnit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I want to test an ActiveMQ messaging (SpringBoot in-memory) system. My problem is that JUnit `@Test` does not allow parameters for methods, but `@JmsListener` needs a parameter. How can I test that case? I have also no clue how to do that with JUnit Parameterized.class? Is there a way to run the test with the SpringBoot `@JmsListener`? Can anyone help me?

Note: The `mqSend.sendJson(`) sends the same jsonString as you can see in the codesnippet.

Thank's for advice.

```
@Autowired
private MqSend mqSend;

@MockBean
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

private String jsonString = "{ \"Number\": \"123456\", \"eMail\": \"mail@dummy.de\", \"Action\": \"add\" }";
private String receivedMessage;

@Before
public void setup() throws IOException {
    this.mqSend.sendJson();
    log.info("Setup done");
}

@Test
@JmsListener(destination = "${jms.queue}")
private void receiveMessageFromMQ(String message) {
    this.receivedMessage = message;
    log.info("Received Message: " + message);
}

@Test
public void test_sending_and_receiving_messages() {
    Assert.assertTrue(this.receivedMessage.equals(this.jsonString));
}
```

}

Comment: Your class makes no sense at all. An `@Test` on an `@JmsListener` method simply doesn't make sense. You should be sending a message from your test and somehow verify if your actual `@JmsListener` method has run.

Comment: Hi, thx for your reply. I still know that this makes not really  sense. This snippet is just to show what I want. Do you have an idea how to verify in a testclass that my JmsListener method has run? And if the JmsListener method does not give me a clue if I received the right message. How can I run this method and how can I get the result to make an assert with that?